# How to store Strings from a CSV file, unless there is another String after the comma?

Tags: java

I have a CSV that contains city names like

```
New York,

Las Vegas,

San Diego,

San Antonio, New York

New York, San Diego
```

When 2 cities are on the same line, they are connected.

So my question is, how can I get each individual city and then also the city that it is connected to?

I was thinking of saving each first instance of each city in an

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

and then adding each connection to the appropriate List but I am not sure how to go about it.

What I have attempted so far is

```
    String filename = "someFilePath";
    File file= new File(fileName);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
  while(scan.hasNext()){
            String line= scan.next();
            String[] cities = line.split(",");
            String city1 = cities[0];
            //String city2 = values[1];
```

The reason I commented city2 out is because I get an ArrayOutOfBounds. When I print out cities, I get just 1 element, and it is just each word. So New, and then York, and then Las etc.

Comment: Share what you have done so far and where you are stuck

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure that you post the code that you have attempted to solve your problem, and if that problem still persists, also post the error that you are getting or the desired output.

Comment: I have added what I have so far.

Comment: You may want to consider `Map<String,Set<String>>` instead.

Comment: How are you planning on storing the list of cities for each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear the form of output data. Also the way you are reading the content from file is wrong. If you do scan.next() it will read each word as separate entity, so in your case it will read as "New" in once scan  "york" in another scan instead of reading it as "New York".

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("./src/city.csv");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./src/city.csv"));
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
        for (String temp = ""; temp != null; temp = in.readLine()) {
            String[] cities = temp.split(",");
            if (cities.length == 1)
                System.out.println(cities[0]);
            if (cities.length > 1)
                System.out.println(cities[0] + " -->" + cities[1]);
        }
        in.close();

    }
}
```

Output:

New York

Las Vegas

San Diego

San Antonio --> New York

New York --> San Diego

Answer (score 1):

```
    String line ="New York, San Diego";
    List<String> city=Arrays.asList(line.split(","));

    //print all cities
    System.out.println("Cities "+city);
    Map<String,List<String>> connectedCities=new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    if(city.size()>1)
    {
        String keyCity=city.get(0);
        connectedCities.put(keyCity, city.subList(1, city.size()));
        //print connected cities
        System.out.println("Connected Cities "+connectedCities);
    }
```

Repeat for all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a map, key will be name of City and value will be Set of String containing names of connected cities.

```
String line ="San Antonio, New York",
String [] arrCities=line.split(", ");
//arrCities[0] ="San Antonio"   is key here
//arrCities[1] ="New York"   is value here

Map<String, Set<String>> citiMap =new HashMap();

 //Check is map contains entries for City
 if(arrCities!=null && arrCities.length>1){
    if(citiMap.contains(arrCities[0]) ){
      //if yes, update Set of cities mapping
       citiMap.put(arrCities[0], citiMap.get(arrCities[0]).add(arrCities[1]));
    }else{
       //create initial city mapping
       Set<String> connections= new HashSet();
       connections.add(arrCities[1]);
      citiMap.put(arrCities[0],connections);
 }
}
```

Repeat same logic for all rows and you shall get desired output